# How to read a binary file from the end to the start in c?

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread, fseek, fgetc

I have tried to read a binary file from end using `fseek()` to move the cursor to the end and `fgetc()` to read the file.

```
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
int size = ftell(fptr);


unsigned char c;

int i =0;

while(i < size){
    c = fgetc(fptr);

    printf("%02X", c);

    printf("\n");
    i++;
```

I have also tired to read the from end by using `fread()` instead

```
while((fread(&line, 1, size, fptr)) == 0){      
for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
       
        //Converting to binary 
        int binary[8];
        for(int j =0; j < 8; j ++){
            binary[7-j]= (line[i] >> (j)) & 1;
            
        }

        for(int n =0; n < 8; n++){
            printf("%d", binary[n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("%02X", line[i]);
        printf("\n");
        // count++;
```

Comment: If you want to read from the end, you'll have to start at the end -1, then seek end-2, etc. I'd recommend against doing this though.

Comment: If you *really* need to do this, memory map the file and use pointers instead of I/o functions.

Comment: But I see you just seek the end to get the size. In this case, you'll have to seek the start afterwards to reset its position.